# How to make an image undroppable on another image

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need to know how to make an image undroppable on another image. I made my image draggable anywhere on the page but i don't want it to be able to be dropped on other images.

Please vote +1 on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this example](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert) in jQuery UI !